# Error: functions firestore is not a valid emulator name, valid options are: ["auth","functions","firestore","database","hosting","pubsub"]

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Estoy usando [Firebase Local Emulator Suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite), todo funciona bien. El emulador arranca correctamente al ejecutar `firebase emulators:start`, y también al ejecutar `firebase emulators:start --only functions` o `firebase emulators:start --only firestore`. El problema surge cuando quiero ejecutar el siguiente comando:

`firebase emulators:start --only functions,firestore`

Es decir, quiero iniciar el emulador solo con esos 2 servicios, el error que recibo es el siguiente:

> Error: firestore functions is not a valid emulator name, valid options are: ["auth","functions","firestore","database","hosting","pubsub"]

¿Existe alguna manera de ejecutar dos servicios en simultaneo y en una sola terminal? He probado ejecutar ambos servicios en terminales separadas y funciona, pero con distintos puertos (4000 y 4001), me gustaría que funcionen en el mismo puerto y en la misma terminal.

Answer (score 0):

si está usando PowerShell, use `firebase start:emulators --only "functions, firestore"` con las comillas dobles. otras líneas de comando como cmd, bash, git bash funcionan normalmente.

Comment: Bienvenido a **StackOverflow en español**, por favor traduce tu respuesta editándola o se expondrá a ser eliminada.